# Get the Values of Option attribute in datalist in HTML5 that is dynamically generated from AJAX Calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, html, html-datalist

I ran into a problem where I was populating the datalist using AJAX(JSON). I want to be able to select the option from the datalist and click on the FIND TIMESHEETS button and do some more ajax calls based on that seleted project Id. My code looks like the following.

MY HTML

```
 <div id="datalist" class="hide">
        <label id="labelPl" for="projectList">Select your project from the list: </label>
        <input type="text" id="ProjName" list="projectList" placeholder=" Project Search by Client's Name : e.g. google, microsoft,caresource etc.">
        <datalist id="projectList"></datalist>
        <button id="find-ts" class="btn btn-primary">Find Timesheets</button>
    </div>
```

MY AJAX THAT SUCESSFULLY POPULATES THE PROJECT LISTS

```
 $('#ProjName').on('input', function (e) {
                var val = $(this).val();
            if (val === "") return;
            var query = $('#ProjName').val();
            var uId=@Model.Id;
            $.getJSON("/Search/Projects", { userId: uId, query: query }, function (data, xhr) {
                var dataList = $('#projectList');
                dataList.empty();
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    var sdate = new Date(parseInt(item.StartDate.substr(6)));
                    formatStartDate = (sdate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + sdate.getDate() + '/' + sdate.getFullYear();
                    var fromatEndDate;
                    if (item.EndDate == null) {
                        fromatEndDate = "Present";
                    }
                    else {

                        fromatEndDate = item.EndDate;
                    }
                    var opt = $("<option class='selected-project' style='min-height:4em'></option>").attr({
                        "value":item.Name + " (from " + formatStartDate + " to " + fromatEndDate + ")",
                        "data-id":item.Id
                    });
                    var select=$('<select id="selectList"></select>')
                    dataList.append(select.append(opt));
                });
            });
```

MY ONCLICK EVENT LISTENER FOR THE BUTTON

```
  $('#find-ts').click(function () {
            //get the id of the selected from datalist
            var val = $('#ProjName').val()
            var selectedId=$('#selectList option:selected').attr('data-id');
            var projId = selectedId ? selectedId : 0; //set it to zero if not found
            //
            console.log("the projectId is ", projId); //This is where I need my projectId so that I can pass in into the controller action method.
            $.ajax({
                url: 'url?projId=' + projId,
                type: 'GET',
                beforeSend: function before() {
                    loadingBar(true);
                },
                complete: function complete() {
                    var myVar = setInterval(function () { loadingBar(false); }, 5000);
                },
                success: function (result) {}
                //doing some calculation here
            });

        });
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that when I click on the FIND TIMESHEETS button I'm getting projId=0 instead of the actual projId of a project that I got back from the JSON

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You have a `datalist` tag. The child elements of `datalist` are `<option>` elements. You seem to be trying to add a `<select>` containing one `<option>` for each item in the collection. And in any case, because of the invalid html your generating `$('#selectList option:selected').attr('data-id');` would only ever return the  `data-id` value of the first `<select>` even if it did work.

Answer (score 1):

You handling the input event of the textbox to add a `<select>` element containing only one `<option>` element with a `data-id` attribute to you `<datalist>` element. A `<datalist>` only requires `<option>` elements. In the buttons click handler, you trying to read `$('#selectList option:selected')`. You have multiple elements with `id="selectList"` (invalid html) but in anycase, selecting an option from a datalist does not add a `selected` attribute to the `<option>`.

Change your scripts to

```
var uId = '@Model.Id';
var url = '@Url.Action("Projects", "Search")'; // dont hard code your urls!
var dataList = $('#projectList'); // cache it

$('#ProjName').on('input', function (e) {
  var query = $(this).val();
  if (!query) {
    return;
  }
  $.getJSON(url, { userId: uId, query: query }, function (data) {
    dataList.empty();
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
      var sdate = // get rid of this and do the formatting on the server and return a string!
      dataList.append($('<option></option>').val(sdate).data('id', data.Id));
      // it should be: dataList.append($('<option></option>').val(item.Text).data('id', item.Id));
    });
  });
});

$('#find-ts').click(function () {
  var text = $('#ProjName').val();
  var option = dataList.children('option').filter(function () {
    return $(this).val() == text;
  })
  var selectedId = option.data('id'); // this will contain the Id
  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("YourAction", "YourController")',
    data { projId: selectedId }, // add the parameters this way
    type: 'GET',
    .....
  });
});
```

Side note: There is no point adding a class name and inline styles to the option elements. They are rendered by the browser/operating system and you have almost no control over how they are rendered.

Comment: Works Good ! Thank you Stephen !